# Chat room issue found?

Tags: discussion, chat

Check the below snapshot. I refresh the page but still the same issue. [Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93330/the-great-gujarati-android-developers-ever)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's working as intended.

If you don't add a message after that "reply", it doesn't format the message as a reply.

As seen [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28956272#28956272), the first one did have a `[space]` after the number, the second one didn't. Both don't get rendered as reply.